# Passing a reference to a buffer between Windows applications

Tags: c#, c++, wpf

I have data sitting in a buffer allocated in application A using AllocHGlobal. I want to use this buffer in application B, i.e. pass a reference between two Windows 7 applications or between an application and a service.

Can this be done with out copying the buffer one or more times?

Thanks.

Comment: Usually you use a stream class to connect different applications.  Using standard input and standard output is one method of accomplishing this.

Comment: [Something like this?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx). You're asking how to implement the solution you've chosen to an unstated problem; if you share the real goal, there may be a better answer.

Comment: Memory is protected, so another app cannot use memory alocated by app.

Comment: @jdweng thanks, but that would require an actual copy of the data through the stream, would it not?

Comment: @ed sorry if I was not clear but I thought passing a reference to another process was clear. I try to keep the questions short and to the point. However, let's say I have a 10MB buffer allocated with AllocHGlobal in process A. I want to access this buffer in process B but I do not want to copy that buffer, I just want to get a reference to that buffer.

Comment: @bwa thanks. This is what I was afraid of. Windows does not seem to have shared memory like Unix does. Memory Mapped Files seems to be the closest.

Comment: @AeroClassics I'm familiar with buffers, but I appreciate the refresher course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can't directly share memory from your process space, you could achieve something similar through the use of a [non-persisted memory-mapped files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your answer that confirms my suspicions. The data really flows one way and using MMF's as data buffers in app A is not practical for the work it has to do. So one copy to a MMF will have to be tolerated. I suspect that this is faster than serializing, or shov9ing the data through a pipe or stream. Probably should experiment with that.